# Reactjs uncaught errors not showing in the browser window - but showing in the console only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have reactjs application when i throw any uncaught error its only showing in my console not in the browser also in devlopment mode . Like in the picture i want to show errors in my browser window also

```
let a = {
    name: "qw",
  };
  console.log(a?.name?.name);
  window.external_SENTRY = Sentry;
  return (
    <div >
      <div >
        <App />
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: The code you added doesn't seem to be related to the error. Also, what build system are you using? CRA, vite?

Comment: Yes, React as default won't send anything to the browser if there is an error.   If you want to show errors in the browser window consider adding an Error Boundary -> https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary

Comment: Well, if you use something like CRA, you should see an error in the browser in development mode when there is a crash during rendering.

Comment: i am using   CRA , but it only shows error in console react version 17.0.0. Even somtimes i throw error but ui doesn't crashed but not responding